# Expression must be constant error declaring array in C

Tags: arrays, c, struct, embedded

I'm trying to make an array of structs but when declaring the array it doesn't want to accept the struct object giving me this error ['Expression must have a constant value'].
I've tried making **pin1** a const before inserting it but it doesn't work as well.

Also all the elements in the struct like **ChannelType** and **PinMode** are typedef enums if that makes a difference.

Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance !

```
#define Active_Pins_No   1

typedef struct Pin{
    ChannelType Pin         ;
    PinMode     Mode        ;
    LevelType   PinValue    ;
    PinDir      Dir         ;
    PinAttach   Attach      ;
    PinCurrent  Current     ;
}PinConfig;

PinConfig pin1 = {F1,DIO,HIGH,OUTPUT,PUR,mA_2} ;
PinConfig pins [Active_Pins_No]  = {pin1}      ;
```

Comment: You should use `PinConfig* pins [Active_Pins_No]  = {&pin1};`.

Comment: Oh thanks that worked, why did it need a pointer to the address this time though ?        I 've made arrays before without this method, is it because of the typedef ?

Comment: Because otherwise you would just copy the value of pin1 to pins[0]. This is not possible in an initialization, because it is not a constant expression. Also updating a value in pin1 will not update pins[0] and the other way around.

Comment: What is your goal in attempting to initialize `pins` with `pin1`? Is `pin1` just a temporary you created for the purpose of this initialization? In that case, you can define the array with `PinConfig pins[Active_Pins_No]  = {{F1,DIO,HIGH,OUTPUT,PUR,mA_2}};`.

Answer (score 1):

You cant use variables (even if declared as `const`) in static storage duration initialisation.

> why did it need a pointer to the address this time though

Because it is a constant expression which is calculated compile time.